# JQuery: Get radio value and perform different operations

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

I have 2 radio inputs. How can I process jquery functions on a selected value on a onchange event?

```
<input value="radio_2way" name="IBE1$IBE_NurFlug1$flightIBE" id="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_radio_2way" checked="checked" type="radio">Hin- und Rückflug &nbsp;&nbsp;<input value="radio_1way" name="IBE1$IBE_NurFlug1$flightIBE" id="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_radio_1way" type="radio">Einfach
```

If the checked value is radio_1way do function1 and if it is radio_2way do function2.

thx a lot, greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just attach a change event to the radio's

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[id^="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1"]').change(function(e){
       var $changed = $(e.target);
       alert($changed.val());
    });
});
```

check the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BUgRV/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("input").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('value') == 'radio_2way'){
              alert('2 way');
             }    
    });
```

Change the above code for your needs. You will want to place the above code in the `$(document).ready()` section.

EDIT:

As pointed out, you likely will need to use `$("input").change` rather then `click`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the change event based on the name, then find the value of the button that is checked and key off it.  Note that the button being changed will be the one that is checked so you can get the value of `this`.   I was originally concerned that their might be two change events triggered (one for the button being checked and another for the button being unchecked).  The two browsers I tested, though, seemed to handle it in a sane way and only generated the change event on the button being checked. Tested in Firefox and Safari.

```
$(function() {
    $('[name=IBE1$IBE_NurFlug1$flightIBE]').change( function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'radio_2way") {
           ...
        }
        else {
           ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: no need to repeat the selector, event.target has the domelement.

Comment: @Jamiec - yes, I realized as a I posted that the button causing the event would be the one that is checked for a radio button.  I've corrected it now.